# how do i implement a basic timestamp in pull to refresh

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented a pull to refresh and now trying to add a timestamp showing "Last updated: "time""(4:50/tuesday etc). I have implemented a method for the same:

```
public void setLastUpdated(CharSequence lastUpdated) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(lastUpdated)) {
            eikonLastUpdated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            eikonLastUpdated.setText(lastUpdated);
        } else {
            eikonLastUpdated.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

Does anyone know how I can add the same to an XML, and how do I go about it, do I also have to add the same to java by calling `settext` method? example:

```
textView.setText("Last updated:");
```

How do I call the `setlastupdated` method for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the chris banes library for the pull to refresh which had a timestamp.Apparently pull to refresh is not native to android and we have to use these libraries to get things working, else you have a lot of work in your hands. link:
https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh